# Change Layout Background in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I want to change the background color of the thread I use in another class. But unfortunately "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" I get an error.

I would be glad if you could help.

```
private class thread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

                while (!change_background) {

                    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is right that only main ui can touch its view. But there is a nice workaround for that. Even if you are on another Thread you can call main Thread using [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //write UI related code in here
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call above vode in uithread or use handler.

`runOnUiThread`

Answer (score 1):

Use runOnUiThread to change background.

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // things need to work on ui thread
    }
});
```